# iOS and Android: Same function, same input, different decimal output

Tags: java, android, ios, swift

we are using the same function in iOS and Android, the same input data, and the output is different from the second/third decimal number.

I can's understand the reason, and we really need to be exact the same outputs.

Following the iOS function:

```
func angleBoundSetFromPosition(userPosition: CLLocationCoordinate2D, distance: Double, bearing: Double) -> (CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
    let dist = Float(distance) / Float(6371)
    let brg = Float(bearing.degreesToRadians)
    let lat1 = Float(userPosition.latitude).degreesToRadians
    let lon1 = Float(userPosition.longitude).degreesToRadians
    let lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(dist) + cos(lat1) * sin(dist) * cos(brg))
    let lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(brg) * sin(dist) * cos(lat1), cos(dist) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2))
    print("for: \(bearing), dist: \(dist), bearing: \(brg),  lat1: \(lat1), lon1: \(lon1), lat2: \(lat2), lon2: \(lon2)")
    return CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: Double(lat2.radiansToDegrees), longitude: Double(lon2.radiansToDegrees))
}
```

Extensions iOS:

```
extension FloatingPoint {
    var degreesToRadians: Self { return self / 180 * .pi}
    var radiansToDegrees: Self { return self * 180 / .pi }
}
```

And here the java:

```
public static LatLng getDestinationPoint(LatLng source, double brng, double dist) {
            dist = dist / 6371;
            brng = Math.toRadians(brng);

            double lat1 = Math.toRadians(source.latitude), lon1 = Math.toRadians(source.longitude);
            double lat2 = Math.asin(Math.sin(lat1) * Math.cos(dist) +
                    Math.cos(lat1) * Math.sin(dist) * Math.cos(brng));
            double lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng) * Math.sin(dist) *
                            Math.cos(lat1),
                    Math.cos(dist) - Math.sin(lat1) *
                            Math.sin(lat2));
            if (Double.isNaN(lat2) || Double.isNaN(lon2)) {
                return null;
            }
            return new LatLng(Math.toDegrees(lat2), Math.toDegrees(lon2));
    }
```

**Input:**

```
UserPosition(45.6091463, 8.8496677)
distance = 10
called once with bearing = -45, and once with bearing 135
```

**Output:**

Android

```
{latitude 45.621861885764005, longitude 8.83148183051733}
{latitude 45.596425230386295, longitude 8.867843324603944}
```

iOS

```
{latitude 45.67270183849526, longitude 8.758660791031469}
{latitude 45.54551866514264, longitude 8.940468486905017}
```

Comment: Edit your question and add the input data you tested with and both the Java and iOS/Swift results.

Comment: How are `degreesToRadians` and `radiansToDegrees` implemented?

Comment: Uopdated with more info

Answer (score 2):

When you convert a function from one language to another, you should try to use the same variable names. In this case, with Java, you might also want to [statically import all Math functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-import-java/) so you don't have a function that actually ends up making comparison impossible.

This is the swift function:

```
let lat2 = asin(sin(lat1)) * cos(newDistance) + cos(lat1) * sin(newDistance) * cos(newBearing)
                         ^
```

This is the prettified Java function:

```
double lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(newDistance) + cos(lat1) * sin(newDistance) * cos(newBearing));
                                                                                                ^
```

Your Swift function has a parenthesis right after the sin, whereas the Java formula has the parenthesis at the end.

As such, the disagreement comes from the fact that neither of these two equations match up, rather than any sort of broken double math.

Double precision drift usually only happens at a small scale. If your test data shows a hugely different value, it is more likely *implementation* is incorrect, rather than *interpretation*.

This is the boxed test code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getDestinationPoint(new LatLng(45.6091463, 8.8496677), -45, 10));
    System.out.println(getDestinationPoint(new LatLng(45.6091463, 8.8496677), 135, 10));
}

public static LatLng getDestinationPoint(LatLng source, double bearing, double distance) {
    double newDistance = distance / 6371;
    double newBearing = toRadians(bearing);
    double lat1 = toRadians(source.latitude);
    double lon1 = toRadians(source.longitude);
    double lat2 = asin(sin(lat1) * cos(newDistance) + cos(lat1) * sin(newDistance) * cos(newBearing));
    double lon2 = lon1 + atan2(sin(newBearing) * sin(newDistance) * cos(lat1), cos(newDistance) - sin(lat1) * sin(lat2));
    if (Double.isNaN(lat2) || Double.isNaN(lon2)) {
        return null;
    }
    return new LatLng(toDegrees(lat2), toDegrees(lon2));
}

static class LatLng {
    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    public LatLng(double lat, double lon) {
        latitude = lat;
        longitude = lon;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return latitude + ", " + longitude;
    }
}
```

Comment: you were right about parenthesis but now the difference is more evidence, I'm going to update the question with some data

Comment: @Miotz my results in plain Java are 45.672701838495264, 8.758660791031469
| 45.545518665142644, 8.940468486905017, match with your iOS/Swift results, not able to reproduce. I am using your code directly from the question, plus dummy class LatLng that stores the values.

Comment: @Miotz attached.

Comment: toRadians() is a java conversion from the swift one? because we still have different output, the only difference is the use of the Math lib

Comment: @Miotz toRadians is built-in Math.toRadians

Answer (score -1):

This issue should occurs only on 'Double' values. 'Floats' should be immune from this.
It has something to do with 'IEEE 754' floating point arithmetics.

If you're interested this is a link: https://www.appinf.com/download/FPIssues.pdf

Comment: this changed only the last few decimal numbers, like from the 9th and so on